# Understanding UUID assignment

Tags: uuid

A UUID (*universal unique identifier*) is a 128 bit code which is used to identify block (storage) devices. Firstly, is this all UUIDs are used for?

How does a device obtain its UUID?

Does it ever change? For instance, on each startup? When a new OS is installed?

How is a UUID generated? Is it random?

Most computers don't have more than 10 storage devices. Why the need for so many different names?

Comment: If you used a very short code it wouldn't be **universally** unique, now, would it?

Comment: @Wildcard it might be, depending on the scope (how many things need/use a  code). This pertains to the first part of my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept is described in [RFC 4122](http://www.rfc-base.org/rfc-4122.html) which defines the various algorithms for generating [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s. Variant 4 uses random numbers and is the most common.

UUIDs are used in many scenarios, a few examples are:

- Labelling partitions and filesystems is the most common usage within Linux
- Network Manager uses them to identify network devices and connections
- Hypervisors, such as Virtual Box and Qemu-KVM, uses them to identify VMs
- The are used within Microsoft Windows where they are knows as [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)s
- They are used for uniqueness within [databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=UUID)
- They are used in [software development](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=UUID)

Within Linux, all distros come with the `util-linux` package, which amongst other things has the `uuidgen` command to generate UUIDs.  This is a front-end to `libuuid` which generates random UUIDs by default, or time-based if not enough entropy is available.

The utility you use to create a partition or filesystem will generate the UUID, which remains with that partition/filesystem until you either re-create them or explicitly change the UUID (for example with `tune2fs`)

UUIDs are used with filesystems and partitions in order to give them a consistent name (although a very long one). This avoids the scenario where the BIOS of UEFI firmware in a two HDD system lists hard disk so that your system disk is allocated `/dev/sda` on one boot and allocated `/deb/sdb` on the next (maybe the first disk was slower to start up on the second boot).

Using the traditional naming method, this would cause havoc in your `/etc/fstab` file as your system would be looking in the wrong disk for partitions to mount.  For example, here is my swap entry:

```
/dev/sda4               none            swap            defaults        0 0
```

If the disks had been allocated differently at boot, my system wouldn't find a fourth partition of type `swap` on the non-system disk (OK, I'm on a laptop, so it hasn't got a second disk, but you get the point) and my swap would fail.

By labeling them with UUIDs, and using those within `/etc/fstab` you're guaranteed that the correct filesystem will be mounted at all times.  For example:

```
UUID=d8ab8967-f2de-4c76-902f-d8d9707c399e /media/files  ext4    defaults 0 0
```

will always mount the partition with that UUID on `/media/files` regardless of the order the BIOS (or UEFI firmware) labels them at boot.

Comment: UUIDS are also commonly used for system identification.

Comment: @garethTheRed Could you please expand on the topic of what (else) UUIDs are used for?